# git hub for mac sync error

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I'm trying to sync a commit to my master branch and I get the following error:

```
It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
    git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
    rm -fr "DOCUMENT PATH/.git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
 (1)
```

I have no idea what this is trying to tell me. can anybody help?

Comment: Did you do what it tells you to do?

Comment: what does rebase mean? 
there's a reason why I'm gitHub for mac, not the command line, being that I don't understand the command line logic...

Comment: See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing and http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: I'm not doing any major changes. all I'm trying to do is sync the changes as I've done hundrets of times before...

Comment: ...and this time it probably lead to a conflict. What does `git status` say? GUIs are nice and all, but Git is a command line tool, and sooner or later you'll run into something like this, so you might as well learn to use it, of only some parts of it. That book that I linked to earlier is a great place to start.

Comment: no they don't apply to developers but people who are used to command line, which are mostly developers...
first of all one would need to explain how to install those tools in the command line and how to get to your repository. I have no idea. I managed to get somewhere where the git command does at least something... on git status I get this: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: There's not much else to say than that you should probably learn the basics of the terminal and some basic Git usage. There are lots of resources online for both of those. If that's not an option then you have a problem with the choice of tools, which is probably out of scope for this question, and probably Stack Overflow in general.

Comment: I really don't like how you assume I do not WANT to learn these things. all I said is there should be an easy interface and if I ask a question like this here I'd like to get a helpful reply that's problem oriented and understandable. as I said, there's a reason I chose to use github for mac and not use github via the command line tools. if there is an application for it, my assumption is that I can do everything with it. if I run into problems I'd like constructive understandable answers. I'd still be happy if anyone could help me with the issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65971/discussion-between-biffen-and-sumi).